# fatal: your current branch appears to be broken

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash

I give this error when I use

```
 git log
```

fatal: your current branch appears to be broken

my branch file was broked 
I opened .git/refs/heads/mybranch in notepad but I see only some 
????????? 
in file

I know I must find branch hash and copy that into .git/refs/heads/mybranch file
but I don't how to find that hash

I read this topic 
[Broken branch in git, fatal: your current branch appears to be broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012869/broken-branch-in-git-fatal-your-current-branch-appears-to-be-broken)

Comment: I suggest trying `git checkout -b new_branch` to create a new branch and then `git branch -D mybranch` to delete your original branch. Then you can rename `new_branch` to whatever you want. Note: this assumes you are currently on the same commit as `mybranch`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

finally, after very pain, this worked for me

```
1 get backup from your .git directory
2 open file .git\logs\refs\heads\<branch name> with your editor 
3 copy second hash of your last line
4 open file .git\refs\heads\<branch name> and delete everything in this file
5 past that hash to .git\refs\heads\<branch name>
```

Comment: The 3rd step should be `Copy the last but one line` or `Copy the second line from the last`