# Git Worktree Got Corrupted Inexplicably

Tags: git, windows-server

### Background

I have 3 Git repos in `Windows Server 2019 Datacenter`, and I am the only one has the access. They are all cloned from another server; I'm just using the server as a PC.

- C:\repoC
- C:\repoD
- C:\repoK

They are all about 1 GB individually. `repoK` is the only one ever got corrupted. And has happend 2 times so far, but I never did anything peculiar, just normal routines.

The only difference of `repoK` from other repos is that it has a second remote `//tsclient/C/repoK.git`. (I use the server via `Remote Desktop` in a `Windows 10` desktop, there is a bare repo `C:\repoK.git` in my desktop).

### The Phenomena

Last time I found it corrupted is when I got to office in the morning. It returns `not a git repository` on every git command. but `.git` folder is present.

This time, it corrupted again, after I came back from supper, but differs from last time. When I use `git status`, it said:

```
No commits yet

Changes to be commited:
...
```

and listed all files as new.

When I use `git log`, it said

```
fatal: your current branch appears to be broken
```

I have pushed all things to my desktop so I'm not worried about my codes. But I wonder why it happend and how to prevent it from happening again?

Comment: What is you branch name ? You can try to fix the ` .git/refs/heads/branch` name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012869/broken-branch-in-git-fatal-your-current-branch-appears-to-be-broken if this is the case.

Comment: Wow, I wonder what clobbered the branch file. That's the thing to figure out here: what's going around removing or overwriting these `.git/refs/heads/` files?